# Ignore rollbar errors from specific environments that are rarely deployed to

Tags: rollbar

I've been trying to reduce the number of irrelevant rollbar errors, such as legitimate users trying to access non-existent images, or malicious bots trying to hack our website by going to `/phpMyAdmin2/`. So far I've managed to reduce the amount of errors by editing the configuration file for rollbar within the application.

However, there's a couple of legacy sites that don't get new deployments very often, and they're providing a large majority of rollbar errors, and it's eating up the quota.

Without doing a new deployment, how can I ignore rollbar errors from those environments, and avoid it eating up the quota? (That is, [muting](https://rollbar.com/docs/status-active-resolved-muted/) won't help, because that still counts towards the quota)

To mitigate the problem, I've gone to "Project Access Tokens" and added a rate limit (167 items per day), so that a burst of activity on one day won't ruin the entire month, but that rate limit is for all environments.

Comment: Possible solution, not yet tested: create new access tokens, and don't rate limit the new access tokens, and make new deployments use those tokens, and heavily rate limit the old, legacy, tokens that are only used by old deployments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm on the team at Rollbar, and I recommend you do exactly as you suggested - Use a new access token for the sites you care about, and put a very tight rate limit on the old access tokens.